# C++ defining a macro that takes a function and pass it to other function, is it possible?

Tags: c++, function, macros

I have a function like this :

```cpp
string inputFormatted(void *errFunc()) {
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "") (*errFunc)();
    return input;
}
```

Which read a string, and shows a error if string was wrong

My errFunc is implemented like this :

```cpp
void errBadKey() {
    cout << "Enter a correct key, try HELP command for more information" << endl;
}
```

I've implemented a macro in this way :

```cpp
#define GET_PARAM(input, errorFunc) do { \
                                        input = inputFormatted(errorFunc); \
                                    } while(0);
```

and I use it like this :

```cpp
int main() {
    string test;
    GET_PARAM(test, errBadKey);
}
```

and I'm wondering why it says `undefined reference to inputFormatted[abi:cxx11](void (*)())`

Is it impossible to pass a function to macro and then pass that function into other function in macro?

Comment: Why are you using a macro?  Just make `GET_PARAM` a function.

Comment: So you mean it's impossible? @NathanOliver

Comment: It's not impossible, and it should work, we'll need a [mcve] to tell you why it doesn't work.  Macros those aren't "safe".  They exist outside the type system.  Using functions makes the code "safer".

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver, I'll use functions but I just wanted to know is it possible with macros or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inputFormatted` function signature must be:

```
string inputFormatted(void errFunc()) {
```

Comment: For the `errFunc` parameter, I was thinking it should be declared as `void (*errFunc)()` instead. `if (input == "")` works just fine, though I would suggest `if (input.empty())` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I agree about `void (*errFunc)()`, but that would be the C way. In C++ we can simplify this. I'd actually write `using Func = void();` and then `string inputFormatted(Func errFunc)`

Comment: I would probably just make the function take a templated callable object instead: `template<class Callable> string inputFormatted(Callable errHandler) { string input; cin >> input; if (input.empty()) errHandler(); return input; }` then it is not limited to just simple functions anymore, it is opened up to lambdas and functors as well.